# how to change the state of radio buttons in rails even after page reloads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a form with radiobuttons. The issue is that in the edit page the radio buttons are staying unselected eventhough the database record is changed..How can i reflect the changes in radiobuttons(or persist the selection even after redirects) aswell?

Here is my radio button code

```
 <div class="form-group boxed-radio radio-big">
                          <label>BedRoom</label>

                          <div>
                            <input type="radio" id="bed_room_1" name="room[bed_room]" value="1"/>
                            <label for="bed_room_1">1</label>

                            <input type="radio" id="bed_room_2" name="room[bed_room]" value="2"/>
                            <label for="bed_room_2">2</label>

                            <input type="radio" id="bed_room_3" name="room[bed_room]" value="3"/>
                            <label for="bed_room_3">3</label>

                            <input type="radio" id="bed_room_4" name="room[bed_room]" value="4"/>
                            <label for="bed_room_4">4+</label>

                          </div>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my radiobutton form to use rails button and now it works..Here is the code if someone needs.

```
<div>
          <%= radio_button("room", "bed_room", "1") %>
          <label for="room_bed_room_1">1</label>

          <%= radio_button("room", "bed_room", "2") %>
          <label for="room_bed_room_2">2</label>

          <%= radio_button("room", "bed_room", "3") %>
          <label for="room_bed_room_3">3</label>

          <%= radio_button("room", "bed_room", "4") %>
          <label for="room_bed_room_4">4+</label>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use attribute 'checked' for radio input. So the code would be

```
<input type="radio" id="bed_room_1" name="room[bed_room]" value="1" checked="<%= 1 == current_value_in_database %>"/>
```

We have to fill in this variable 'current_value_in_database'

Comment: Is this the only way? Do i really need to put the erb in every radio?

Comment: You don't need to put in every radio, you may use a forloop here

Comment: Still do i have to match it with the database like that??Can i pass hidden field instead?

Comment: This should theoretically work but its not working in my case this method is not working..

Comment: I tried like this  <input type="radio" id="bed_room_3" name="room[bed_room]" value="3" checked="<%= 3 == @room.bed_room %>"/>

Comment: Hmm weird, what is the data type of @room.bed_room?

Comment: didnt saw your question..Its an integer

Comment: found the issue..The issue was that for radio button there is no boolean attribute. We just add 'checked' to the field which we want to be checked.

Comment: If its rails helpers we can do checked: true and so.. But it wont work while using pure html. In addition if we are using rails helpers we can do like the answer I provide and it will take care of it all by saving us several lines of code for selecting button based on database value...Thank you for your help..